# How do I re-use Capybara sessions between tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, capybara

I want to keep on using the same session and by that I mean Rails' session between various `Test::Unit` integration tests that use Capybara. The `Capybara::Session` object is the same in all the tests as it is re-used, but when I access another page in another test, I'm immediately logged out.

Digging in I found that `capybara_session.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies` is cleared between one test and the next.

Any ideas how? or why? or how to avoid it?

Trying to work-around that, I saved the cookie in a class variable and re-added later by running:

```
capybara_session.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie(@@cookie)
```

and it seems to work, the cookie is there, but when there's a request, the cookie gets replaced for another one, so it had no effect.

Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am hitting it, and have tried all the solutions proposed below, to no avail...

Answer (score 18):

Add the following after your capybara code that interacts with the page:

```
Capybara.current_session.instance_variable_set(:@touched, false)

or

page.instance_variable_set(:@touched, false)
```

If that doesn't work, these might help:

https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access

http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2012/01/05/capybara-cucumber-and-how-the-cookie-crumbles/

Comment: I love you, man! :) This worked *great*. I ran into problems with rspec-steps, regarding a context inside a context (might be specific to our test setup; we're patching rspec's context).

Comment: Worked with the gem rack_session_access. Nice work !

Comment: great, adding "page.instance_variable_set(:@touched, false)" to the global after(:each) block and "page.instance_variable_set(:@touched, true)" to the global after(:all) saved us about 20% of test runtime (with >250 capybara test blocks). Luckily the tweak resulted in only about 1% of new test fails which can esily be fixed. NICE!!! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'm writing tests for an Angular SPA and it was insane to think that I would have to wait for a full page reload, downloading all of the .js assets again after every test.

Comment: Works good, Capybara 2.16. But in the final `after(:context)` you need also to do `page.reset!` after `page.instance_variable_set(:@touched, true)`, otherwise it's not reset.

Comment: Thank you so much I have been trying to fix this for along  time.

Answer (score 5):

If what you are doing is trying to string together individual examples into a story (cucumber style, but without cucumber), you can use a gem called rspec-steps to accomplish this.  For example, normally this won't work:

```
describe "logging in" do
  it "when I visit the sign-in page" do 
    visit "/login"
  end
  it "and I fill in my registration info and click submit" do
    fill_in :username, :with => 'Foo'
    fill_in :password, :with => 'foobar'
    click_on "Submit"
  end
  it "should show a successful login" do
    page.should have_content("Successfully logged in")
  end
end
```

Because rspec rolls back all of its instance variables, sessions, cookies, etc.

If you install rspec-steps (note: currently not compatible with rspec newer than 2.9), you can replace 'describe' with 'steps' and Rspec and capybara will preserve state between the examples, allowing you to build a longer story, e.g.:

```
steps "logging in" do
  it "when I visit the sign-in page" #... etc.
  it "and I fill in" # ... etc.
  it "should show a successful" # ... etc.
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent the call to `@browser.manage.delete_all_cookies` that happens between tests by monkey patching the `Capybara::Selenium::Driver#reset!` method. It's not a clean way of doing it, but it should work...

Add the following code to your project so that it is executed *after* you `require 'capybara'`:

```
class Capybara::Selenium::Driver < Capybara::Driver::Base
  def reset!
    # Use instance variable directly so we avoid starting the browser just to reset the session
    if @browser
      begin
        #@browser.manage.delete_all_cookies <= cookie deletion is commented out!
      rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError => e
        # delete_all_cookies fails when we've previously gone
        # to about:blank, so we rescue this error and do nothing
        # instead.
      end
      @browser.navigate.to('about:blank')
    end
  end
end
```

For interest's sake, the offending line can be seen in Capybara's codebase here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb#L71

Comment: That function is not being run between tests. I actually commented it out in my gem and it didn't make any difference (I also set a breakpoint there and it wasn't reached). I think it might be run for RSpec, where Capybara has some deep integration, but not for Test::Unit. That's why this problem is so puzzling.

Comment: Interesting problem!

So `reset!` is executed for rspec tests here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L14 and for cucumber tests here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb#L10 ... the plot thickens...

I presume you've gone through this: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-testunit

Comment: This worked for me! Certain tests I dont want to clear the browser in between so i do @browser.navigate.to('about:blank') based on a global variable that certain tests modify

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth posting the reason why you need this kind of behaviour. Usually, having the need to monkey patch Capybara, is an indication that you are attempting to use it for something it was not intended for. It is often possible to restructure the tests, so that you don't need the cookies persisted across integration tests.

Comment: To speed up the tests. Leaving the session intact is (generally) not a violation of test isolation